# List Value Members of a databound CheckedListBox

Tags: c#

I have a CheckedListBox in win form that gets loaded from the database with the code below.  My question is how can I get a list of keys of the Checked Value Members?

An example data set looks like this...

```
ID  Descr      IsChecked
4   East        1
1   Loc Code    1
2   North       1
3   South       0
5   West        0
```

So my goal is to fill a variable StrLocKeys with "4,1,2" with the example data above.

```
public DataTable LoadLocationCheckedListBox(int coid, int userid)
    {
        string strSql = "plm_admin_location_checkedlistbox_by_user";
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cnxn);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("coid", SqlDbType.Int);
        p1.Value = coid;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("userid", SqlDbType.Int);
        p2.Value = userid;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

        SqlDataAdapter Ada = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Ada.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

The LoadLocationCheckedListBox is called in a win form load event and contains three columns (ID int, Descr varchar(50), IsChecked int).  The Display and Value Member are set and then uses the IsChecked value to set the checked state in a foreach loop

```
            // load the locations and then idenfify the checked items
            DataTable src_loc = da.LoadLocationCheckedListBox(coid,userid); 
            clbLocations.DataSource = src_loc;
            clbLocations.DisplayMember = "Descr";
            clbLocations.ValueMember = "ID";

            if (mode == "Edit")
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in src_loc.Rows)
                {
                    if( row["IsChecked"].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        // check the item in the checkbox list
                        int i = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString());
                        clbLocations.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried the MSDN exmaple below but it returns "System.Data.DataRowView" rather than the Value Member.

```
 foreach (int indexChecked in clbLocations.CheckedIndices)
        {
            // The indexChecked variable contains the index of the item.
            MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" +
                            clbLocations.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString() + ".");
            MessageBox.Show(clbLocations.Items[indexChecked].ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(clbLocations)
        }
```

I use the following in ASP.Net with System.Web.UI.WebControls and it works fine.  I just need something similar for win forms.

```
string GetListBoxSelections(CheckBoxList cb)
    {
        string rv = string.Empty;
        // Iterate through the Items collection of the CheckBoxList 
        // control and build a string of the selected items.
        string c = cbContactTypes.Items.Count.ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < cb.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cb.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                // here i need to build a string...
                // for example if check box list items 2,5 & 8 are selected then
                // i need to buld a string equal to "2,5,8"
                // this enables will enable me to bulk insert or update contact types 
                // and interfaces per contact with the Support.Contact_Save stoed procedure
                string Separator = rv.Length > 0 ? "," : "";
                rv += Separator + cb.Items[i].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: The "ToString()" is giving wrong results.  Try value instead.

Comment: Value doesn't exist for clbLocations.Items[indexChecked]

Comment: object is null.  Did you try "IsChecked**".  Your sample data has two asterisks.

Comment: astericks are a type error.  I tried to bold the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I came up with a good solution.  First load the check box list as before:

```
                // load the locations and then idenfify the checked items
            DataTable src_loc = da.LoadLocationCheckedListBox(coid,userid); 
            clbLocations.DataSource = src_loc;
            clbLocations.DisplayMember = "Descr";
            clbLocations.ValueMember = "ID";

            SetLocationKeys(clbLocations,src_loc);
```

Calling SetLocationKeys and passing the control and the data table handles checking the appropriate check boxes:

```
    private void SetLocationKeys(CheckedListBox cb, DataTable dt)
    {
        int index = 0;

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (r.ItemArray[2].ToString() == "1")
            {
                cb.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```css
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Descr", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("IsChecked", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4,"East", 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"Loc Code", 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2,"North", 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3,"South", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5,"West", 0});

            List<int> StrLocKeys = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("IsChecked") == 1).Select(y => y.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();​
```